# How to check if email exists in p tag using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup to try and check if there is an email address in a paragraph tag within a div tag. I'm for looping through a list of the divs:

```
for div in list_of_divs:
```

Where each div:

```
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>hereIsAnEmail@gmail.com</p>
</div>
```

Within the for loop, I have:

```
email = div.find(name="p", string=re.compile("^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$"))
```

The name="p" is working fine, but I'm not sure what to put for the string. Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: please include enough code to provide an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). what is `reply`?

Comment: @wpercy sorry, I just changed the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
html="""<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>hereIsAnEmail@gmail.com</p>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
list_of_divs = soup.find_all('div')
for div in list_of_divs:
    emails = div.find_all("p", string=re.compile(r"^[\w.-]+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+\w{2,4}$"))
    print([em.text for em in emails])
```

Output: `['hereIsAnEmail@gmail.com']`

Note that `^[\w.-]+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+\w{2,4}$` is quite restrictive, you might possible want to use a more generic one like `^\S+@\S+\.\S+$` that matches 1+ non-whitespace chars, `@`, 1+ non-whitespace chars, `.` and again 1+ non-whitespace chars.

Notes on the code:

- With `div.find_all("p", string=re.compile(r"^[\w.-]+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+\w{2,4}$"))`, you get all child `p` tags of the current `div` element whose text matches the regex pattern fully
- `print([em.text for em in emails])` prints just texts of all the found `p` nodes with only emails in them.